# filter words that are in english dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, nltk, cpu-word

I am parsing words from xml files and I need to filter out only words in English dictionary. The parsed words can be plural or past tense, etc. But the word in the list should remain in its original tense after being verified by NLTK English word corpus (English dictionary).

I tried to use the vocabulary list from `nltk.corpus.words`, to find intersected words with the contents. I don't see an error, but there's no result data. I am not sure what the problem is.

How can filter out those words into a new list?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
     html = response.read()

import math
import random
import requests
import collections
import string
import re
import MySQLdb as mdb
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob import Word
from textblob.wordnet import VERB
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from string import punctuation
from oauthlib import *
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
import requests, re

from collections import Counter
from lxml import html
from operator import itemgetter

def process(url, xpath):
            """
            Downloads a feed url and extracts the results with a variable path
            :param url: string
            :param xpath: string
            :return: list
            """
            contents = requests.get(url)
            root = ET.fromstring(contents.content)
            return [element.text.encode('utf8') if element.text is not None else '' for element in root.findall(xpath)]



    ## XML PARSING
def main(n=10):

        # A list of feeds to process and their xpath


        feeds = [
            {'url': 'http://www.nyartbeat.com/list/event_type_print_painting.en.xml', 'xpath': './/'},
            {'url': 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/FriezeMagazineUniversal?format=xml', 'xpath': './/'},
            {'url': 'http://www.artandeducation.net/category/announcement/feed/', 'xpath': './/'},
            {'url': 'http://www.blouinartinfo.com/rss/visual-arts.xml', 'xpath': './/'},
            {'url': 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/ContemporaryArtDaily?format=xml', 'xpath': './/'},
            {'url': 'http://www.e-flux.com/category/announcements/feed/', 'xpath': './/'},
            {'url': 'http://www.e-flux.com/category/journal/feed/', 'xpath': './/'}

        ]



        # A place to hold all feed results
        results = []

        # Loop all the feeds
        for feed in feeds:
            # Append feed results together
            results = results + process(feed['url'], feed['xpath'])

        # Join all results into a big string
        contents=",".join(map(str, results))

        # Remove double+ spaces
        contents = re.sub('\s+', ' ', contents)

        # Remove everything that is not a character or whitespace
        contents = re.sub('[^A-Za-z ]+', '', contents)


        words_split = [w.lower() for w in contents.split() if len(w) <=13 ]
        wordlist = [w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words() ]

        words_sort = [val for val in words_split if val in wordlist]


        # Count the words
        word_count = Counter(words_sort)

        # Clean the content a little
        filter_words = ['art', 'artist', 'artists']
        for word in filter_words:
                if word in word_count:
                    del word_count[word]


    ##
        words = word_count.most_common(n)
        words = sorted(words, key = itemgetter(1))

        out = []
        for word, count in words:
            out += [word]*count

        final = " ".join(out)

        with open("filename.txt","w+") as f:
            f.write(final)





def process(url, xpath):
        """
        Downloads a feed url and extracts the results with a variable path
        :param url: string
        :param xpath: string
        :return: list
        """
        contents = requests.get(url)
        root = ET.fromstring(contents.content)
        return [element.text.encode('utf8') if element.text is not None else '' for element in root.findall(xpath)]




    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

---

```
  import math
    import random
    import requests
    import collections
    import string
    import re
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
    import nltk

def process(url, xpath):
    """
    Downloads a feed url and extracts the results with a variable path
    :param url: string
    :param xpath: string
    :return: list
    """
    contents = requests.get(url)
    root = ET.fromstring(contents.content)
    return [element.text.encode('utf8') if element.text is not None else '' for element in root.findall(xpath)]


  def main(n=50000):

    feeds = [{'url': 'http://www.nyartbeat.com/list/event_type_print_painting.en.xml',
              'xpath': './/'},
             {'url': 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/FriezeMagazineUniversal?format=xml',
              'xpath': './/'}]   

    results = []

    # Loop all the feeds
    for feed in feeds:
        # Append feed results together
        results.extend(process(feed['url'], feed['xpath']))

    # Join all results into a big string
    contents = ",".join(map(str, results))

    # Remove double+ spaces
    contents = re.sub('\s+', ' ', contents)

    # Remove everything that is not a character or whitespace
    contents = re.sub('[^A-Za-z ]+', '', contents)

    words_split = [w.lower() for w in contents.split() if len(w) <=13 ]

    wordlist = [w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words() ]

    words = [val for val in words_split if val in wordlist]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: what is `process` in this line `results.extend(process(feed['url'], feed['xpath']))` ?

Comment: I have added codes for 'process' thanks.

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but if you run this program as-is, there will be no output as you aren't printing anything.

Comment: That's right...how are you checking that there are no result data?..because I just ran your code and I got a whole bunch of words...

Comment: really? Do you see the NLTK filtering works? or do I need the lemmatized NLTK word set to find intersection? I check the result from the text file generated with mysqldb update. I will upload the whole code.

Comment: Actually, to be correct, I only checked up to `words_split = [w.lower() for w in contents.split() if len(w) <=13 ]` ...to make sure you are getting the words...I don't have `NLTK` module installed ..

Comment: is there other method to do this? textBlob?